# Issue with Yii's listData

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

I have a model called managers, I want to create a drop down list that pulls the managers names based on the managers id. I am using the code below

```
echo $form->dropDownList
(
  $model,'country', 
  CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'value1','value2'), 
  array('empty'=>;'--please select--')
);
```

The drop down list actually gives me the desired names('value') but wont display the default empty array value, how can I get the 'please select' bit displaying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo $form->dropDownList
(
  $model,'country', 
  CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'value1','value2'), 
  array('prompt'=>'--please select--')
);
```

The prompt keyword should do the trick.  That's how I display it.